# how to parse an xml file from view did load method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml, xcode4

In my application I have a login page were the user can log in.
Once the user has logged-in to his account, he should go to his dashboard page(home page).
On the dashboard page there are three buttons <kbd>add</kbd>, <kbd>edit</kbd> and <kbd>logout</kbd> but in a dashboard page I call the URL to read the XML file from `viewDidLoad` method before pressing any button.

I want to parse the XML file and save its value on the same page.

I have tried to parse the XML file on save page and I am using the value of the XML file on same page but I am not able to use that string value in another function on same page.
but I am not able to use the string `user_login_xml` in the above method which is on the same page.. instead I get an error `exc_bad_access`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    NSString *EditProfileID=Dataid;
    NSString* result = [EditProfileID stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    NSString *urlAsString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mybusinesscentral.co.uk/mobile/iphone_profile_id.php?id="];

    urlAsString=[urlAsString stringByAppendingString:result];
    NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString]];

    urlCon = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    if (urlCon) 
                {
                    NSMutableData *mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
                    self.receivedData=mutableData;
                    [mutableData release];
                }       
                else //connection failed.
                {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
    initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Error")
    message:NSLocalizedString(@"Error connecting to remote server", @"Error connecting to remote server")delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", @"Ok") otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                    [alert release];
                }
                [req release];
        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
        {
            [receivedData setLength:0];
        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data1 
        {
            [receivedData appendData:data1];
        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
        {
            [connection release];
            self.receivedData = nil; 

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed! Error - %@ (URL: %@)", [error localizedDescription],[[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]] 
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }

        - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
        {
            NSString *receivedDataAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            [receivedDataAsString release];

            xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
            [xmlParser setDelegate:self]; 
            [xmlParser parse];

            [connection release];
            self.receivedData = nil;
        }

        - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
        {
            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"details"])
            {
                NSString *user_login = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"user_login"];
                user_login_xml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user_login];
        }
        }

        -(IBAction)Btn_AddNew:(id)sender
        {
            if ([user_login_xml length]==0) 
            {
                AddNew *addnew = [[AddNew alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddNew" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:addnew animated:YES];
            }
            else 
            {
                SubmitYourListing_Active *SubmitListing=[[SubmitYourListing_Active alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubmitYourListing_Active" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                SubmitListing.UserID=Dataid;
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:SubmitListing animated:YES];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tell me one thing,why aren't you passing anything in urlAsString for value id?

Comment: write down [user_login_xml retain] after fetching the value and try again.

Comment: can u please edit the code bcoz m confuse were to write [user_login_xml retain]..please

Comment: can u check my method ...is it right or wrong...thank you

Comment: See, you can get a direction over here,nobody can do spoon feeding at this level. hope u r getting my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using TouchXMl, you can download from

https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML

and installation guide Click [here](http://foobarpig.com/iphone/touchxml-installation-guide.html)

This is the easiest way to parse xml file, only few lines of code required.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it's useful to you, but it's very useful to me check out the [TouchXML](http://sugartin.info/category/iphone-dev/accessingnetwork/touchxml/)